# I want to check if the item is purchased before, v4 In-App billing

Tags: android, in-app-billing, billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

I have a non-consumable one time item.  I want to check if item is already purchased or not before launching the purchase flow. I tried lots of things but nothing worked. I searched about it but I couldn't find a solution for v4. Can you help me please?

```
       billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(
                         BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP,
                         new PurchasesResponseListener() {
                             @Override
                             public void onQueryPurchasesResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @NonNull List<Purchase> list) {
                                 if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                                     for (Purchase purchase : list) {

                                         if (purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
                                             //handlePurchase(purchase);
                                             savePurchaseValueToPref(true);
                                         }
                                     }
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                 );
```

I put this code in onBillingSetupFinished but it didn't work as I wanted

Comment: Did you find any solution mate , Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can save a flag to sharedPrerences, and check the flag is true or false to launch the purchase flow